# Add an index (numeric ID) column to large data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a read large csv file into a data frame. Data in the csv file are from multiple web sites representing user information. For example here is the structure of the data frame.

```
user_id, number_of_logins, number_of_images, web
001, 34, 3, aa.com
002, 4, 4, aa.com
034, 3, 3, aa.com
001, 12, 4, bb.com
002, 1, 3, bb.com
034, 2, 2, cc.com
```

as you can see once I bring the data into the data frame user_id is no longer a unique id and this causes all the analysis. I am trying to add another columns prior to `user_id` which is something like `"generated_uid"` and pretty much use the index of the `data.frame` to be filled by that column. What's the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: a simple approach is to add new column with increasing numbers: `data.frame$generated_uid <- 1:nrow(data.frame)`

Comment: Note that the sometimes suggested dplyr::row_number() ranks the data and thus not necessarily respect the row order of the original data set.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

You can add a sequence of numbers very easily with

```
data$ID <- seq.int(nrow(data))
```

If you are already using `library(tidyverse)`, you can use

```
data <- tibble::rowid_to_column(data, "ID")
```

Answer (score 132):

Using alternative *dplyr* package:

```
library("dplyr")

df <- df %>% mutate(id = row_number())
```

Comment: This approach also works for creating unique identifiers inside groups: `df <- df %>% group_by(group_var) %>% mutate(id = row_number())`. Inside each group, `id` then counts from 1 to n.

Comment: This function should be used with caution since it is a ranking function and will assign values depending on ranking ("A,B,C" gets "1,2,3" but "C,A,B" gets "3,1,2") so if the original order is important it is better to use the accepted answer.

Answer (score 31):

If your `data.frame` is a `data.table`, you can use special symbol `.I`:

```
data[, ID := .I]
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, if I understand you correctly. You can do something like the following.

To show it, I first create a `data.frame` with your example

```
df <- 
scan(what = character(), sep = ",", text =
"001, 34, 3, aa.com
002, 4, 4, aa.com
034, 3, 3, aa.com
001, 12, 4, bb.com
002, 1, 3, bb.com
034, 2, 2, cc.com")

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(df, 6, 4, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(df) <- c("user_id", "number_of_logins", "number_of_images", "web")
```

You can then run one of the following lines to add a column (at the end of the `data.frame`) with the row number as the generated user id. The second lines simply adds leading zeros.

```
df$generated_uid  <- 1:nrow(df)
df$generated_uid2 <- sprintf("%03d", 1:nrow(df))
```

If you absolutely want the generated user id to be the first column, you can add the column like so:

```
df <- cbind("generated_uid3" = sprintf("%03d", 1:nrow(df)), df)
```

or simply rearrage the columns.