# How to create a tibble with hierarchically and arbitrary grouped variables mapped to unique values?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, hierarchical-data, tibble

Is there an elegant and generic way to reproduce below tibble ?

```
data.frame(First=rep(c('A', 'B'), each=2),
       Second=rep(c(1, 2), each=4),
       Third=rep(c('true', 'false')),
       Unique=1:8, stringsAsFactors = F) %>% as.tibble()
```

output:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>First</th><th> Second</th><th> Third</th><th> Unique</th></tr><tr><td>&lt;chr&gt;  </td><td>&lt;int&gt; </td><td>&lt;chr&gt;  </td><td>&lt;dbl&gt;</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>1 </td><td>true</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>1 </td><td>false</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>1 </td><td>true</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>1 </td><td>false</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>2 </td><td>true</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>2</td><td>false</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>2 </td><td>true</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>2</td><td>false</td><td>8</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: ?expand.grid   123

Comment: yeah.. you can use expand.grid, order / arrange it then give the numbers?

Comment: If the order is not important you can also use `crossing` from `tidyr` i.e `crossing(First = c('A', 'B'), Second = 1:2, Third = c(TRUE, FALSE))`

Comment: It's just a row index, you can add it by using  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518605/add-an-index-numeric-id-column-to-large-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` functions, you can do :

```
tidyr::crossing(First = c('A', 'B'), Second = 1:2, Third = c(TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(Unique = row_number())


#  First Second Third Unique
#  <chr>  <int> <lgl>  <int>
#1 A          1 FALSE      1
#2 A          1 TRUE       2
#3 A          2 FALSE      3
#4 A          2 TRUE       4
#5 B          1 FALSE      5
#6 B          1 TRUE       6
#7 B          2 FALSE      7
#8 B          2 TRUE       8
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi this should do the work.

```
expand.grid(first = c('A', 'B'), second = 1:2, third = c("true", "false")) %>% 
  mutate(Unique = 1:n())
```